# Nuget push command Keep asking for MS credentials

Tags: nuget

I am going to push the NUGET PUSH. It keeps me asking for credential in pop up, untill the session expires.

> Credential Plugin..... 300 timed out.

Anything or tip on what to update on CLI.

Answer (score 1):

The nuget.exe was old. so updating it worked.

> nuget.exe update -self

To me, this has given another associated Error Authentication Failure.

Step 1: Check you have access to the VSTS on the online visualstudio.
Step 2: if you have access, then Go to

> Artifacts >> Connect to Feed

Download the "Nuget + Credential Provider"

Update it on Your drive e.g (C:F: etc) [Copy/Paste the exes]

> CredentialProvider.VSS.exe -U "your-source-olnie-on-vsts-repo" -I

This command must generate a prompt for your VS credential and your user name along apikey (dont-share-it-with-anyone). Then you are good.

Try pushing the package and you are done.